# Set basic auth for JSON requests and devise auth for Html requets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, devise, basic-authentication

I have a controller named topics. When I visit the page that should be authenticated by devise gem. But, using POSTMAN for testing JSON requests, shows a error like this..

```
{
"error": "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."
}
```

This causes due to the devise authentication. In order to avoid this issue, I simply put as a

```
skip_before_action:authenticate_user!
```

In my opinion this ignores the authentication. If there is any way to use devise normal authentication for HTML request and API basic authentication for JSON requests?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code from the Devise [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-HTTP-Auth-Basic-with-Devise).

However, in my opinion, it is better to have separate controllers for users and API. Then, use Devise for users and any other authentication mechanism for the API requests.